# Какой существует способ гарантировать обязательную проверку в каждой реализации класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс - многоугольник

```
template <class Selector>
class NGon;
```

Есть несколько селекторов:

```
struct _3selector{};
struct _4selector{};
```

И, соответственно, столько же реализаций класса NGon:

```
template <>
class NGon<_3selector> {/* очень полезный треугольник */};

template <>
class NGon<_4selector> {/* очень полезный четырехугольник */};
```

Я хочу, чтобы при создании очередной реализации происходила проверка того, что класс наследуется, например, от

```
class INGon {};
```

То есть, в следующем случае должна быть ошибка компиляции, так как **NGon<_5selector>** не наследуется от **INGon**

```
struct _5selector{};

template <>
class NGon<_5selector> {/* очень полезный пятиугольник */}; // ошибка компиляции: Я упаль :(
```

А в случае, когда наследование есть, ошибок быть не должно

```
struct _6selector{};

template <>
class NGon<_6selector> : INGon {/* очень полезный шестиугольник*/}; // ошибок компиляции нет
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Про std::is_base я знаю, вопрос только в том, куда его засунуть.

Comment: Гм... Поскольку у вас это специализации, эта проверка должна быть в каждой из них. Но вы и так их создаете вручную, т.е. знаете, кто наследует, кто нет?

Comment: Именно в таком виде это невозможно. Если у вас есть какая-то шаблонная функция, куда вы передаете эти классы, можно проверять в ней через `is_base`...